# Can I legally include an expense made to a school that was later refunded? (American Opportunity Tax Credit)

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, tax-credit

This is ethically questionable, I'm sure of that. However, this is an expense that was made and should be, according to the information I am provided, acceptable. This is also a purchase that will not show up on a 1098-T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not expense something you didn't spend. A payment refunded is not payment paid.

Comment: Just to be clear, this was an amount paid in full and then later refunded (weeks later). Your answer still applies correct?

Comment: Of course. Generally if you claim American Opportunity Tax Credit, but the tuition amount doesn't match 1098-T - prepare to be audited.

Comment: My understanding of the AOTC is that the expenses you are claiming are tuition + non-tuition (books & materials that are required by the school or not required but needed). So a computer, for example, can be included if your course requires you to type up an essay. In addition, they give you $1000/yr for 4 years if you claim it, without claiming any additional expenses.

Comment: I don't think you're right. Go through the publication 970 again. You can definitely **not** include a computer for this credit, unless it is explicitly required and only used for your studies - which is rarely the case. Quote: *- **Qualified expenses**: 
Tuition, required enrollment fees, and course materials that the student needs for a course of study whether or not the materials are bought at the educational institution as a condition of enrollment or attendance*.

Comment: Relying on chances of being audited is generally a bad idea. This is called "audit roulette", is a sign of fraud, and may cause the IRS to remove the statute of limitations from your relevant returns (there's no statute of limitation on fraud).

Comment: Condition of enrollment is **not** a criterion.